# how to play embedded video file in WMPLib

Tags: c#

I have a  video file "1.mp4" embedded in my project. How can play this file in WMPLib?

```
Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream _videoStreamReader = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("my namespace.1.mp4");
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL =  _videoStreamReader;
```

Throws:

> Cannot convert System.IO.Stream to string

WMPLib cant play stream video file?

or

other video player componennt do ?

Comment: Why the vb6 tag?

Comment: You can't use embedded resources with WMPLib but you can put the file in your application folder and play it from there. [MSDN example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ace161f1-e14b-4198-9976-f402283e6e6c/media-player-to-play-my-resources?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: other video player componnent can play embedded video file?